# Incorporation Of A Printer-Friendly Option?

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to have a **printer-friendly** option for the odd occassion when a solution may need to be printed out (in a nice neatly fashion) ?

Comment: See also: [Printing out Stack Overflow Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877/187228)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a third-party solution available at [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) ([StackApps entry here](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)), which also has a userscript and bookmarklet available.

Comment: Thanks for that Bob, sounds interesting ;)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the current printing?

FireFox:

[image]

Internet Explorer:

[image]

Sure there may be a few things that aren't necessary (i.e. "Not the answer you're...." bit) but overall it's a pretty clean solution IMO.